# Custom Validaton on an Element in Angular2

Tags: angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

I have Got an input element `<input type="text" name="password">` and it is not inside any form . How can I implement any Custom validation like  required, minimum password Length onto this ?

Comment: take min length in input filed

Answer (score 0):

Input elements can still use the built-in validator directives without being inside a `form` element.

They just need to be a form control e.g. marked with the `ngModel` attribute. The example input field below is marked with `ngModel` and the `required` validator so it's validation status will be tracked and synced with the model.

`<input name="fullName" ngModel required>`

See the document for the [NgModel](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel) directive for more details.